# Google Api and Google Auth Library which one should I use for GoogleOAuth2

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

What are the differences between those those two libraries?
Which one should I use for authentication?

- https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client
- https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs

for example: 
I saw that while one include the setCredentials, the other doesn't support it. and have credentials as a property

Comment: The first one is in alpha i would guess its a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it appears that the first one is indeed in alpha.
Also, the second one is official release and maintained by google fellows, and yesterday was released it 1.0.0 version. 
see it here as well -> https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/241

Comment: I had the same question. I gonna go for https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs too because it's the one documented in the doc, for example https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth